# Updating height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm building a table that shows an entry for a user. One of the cells shows a set of "tags" downloaded from the server. I am currently building a set of UILabels and manually adding them to a view contained in the cell. While this works, the cell does not dynamically resize after adding the tags. The tags overlap the cell beneath it and I can't figure out how to manually update the height of the cell.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
JournalTagsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JournalTagsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


//Check if we have any tags to show
if(self.journalObject.journalEntryTags != nil){
    cell.placeholderLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.tagsView = [self updateTagsView:cell.tagsView];
}

return cell;
```

The following is my method for actually creating each tag, laying them out and adding them to the view:

```
- (void)updateTagsView:(UIView*)viewToUpdate{

    NSArray *items = self.journalObject.journalEntryTags;
    //Clean up the view first
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [viewToUpdate subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    float x = 10;
    float y = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.count; i++) {

        CGRect textRect = [items[i] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 1000)
                                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont tagCopy]}
                                                 context:nil];
        CGSize size = textRect.size;


        if (x+size.width > (self.view.frame.size.width-20)) {
            y += size.height + 10;
            x = 10;
        }


        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, size.width, size.height)];
        lbl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", items[i]]];
        [lbl setFont:[UIFont tagCopy]];
        [lbl sizeToFit];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.145 green:0.392 blue:0.576 alpha:1.000]];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.804 green:0.871 blue:0.914 alpha:1.000]];
        lbl.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        lbl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.145 green:0.392 blue:0.576 alpha:1.000].CGColor;
        lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        [lbl.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [viewToUpdate addSubview:lbl];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userClickedOnTag:)];
        [lbl addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        x += size.width + 10;

        if (x > (self.view.frame.size.width-20)) {
            y += size.height + 10;
            x = 10;
        }

        if (i == items.count-1) {
            y+= size.height + 20;
        }
    }


    [viewToUpdate setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, y)];
}
```

However, I don't know how to manually update the height for this cell based on the size of this view. I don't want/need to manually calculate the height of every single cell, just this one which is why I'm not currently using **heightForRowAtIndexPath** but I don't know how to update the height of this one cell. Obviously I can calculate the height I need for this cell if necessary as I'm already setting up the view frame that holds the tags, but short of having to go through every single cell and manually calculate each ones height, I'm stumped.

Comment: use auto layout, pin this view four corners to cells

Comment: Under iOS 8 autolayout can automatically provide the height of a cell to the TableView. But this only works if you're using constraints; if you're adding subview programatically you would also need to add constraints programatically.

Answer (score 1):

*I think* you will have to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I'm not sure you completely understand what's happening. Or maybe I have it wrong.. Either way, how I understand it: The total height of the "cell" will always be presented. You never set the "height" of the cell, it will automatically show the entire content. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is not a way to tell the cell how tall it should be, but rather how much space the **tableView** should *reserve* for that particular cell. If you pass a height too short, it will still present the entire cell, but the next cell will start too soon. It also works the other way around, if you pass a bigger number than necessary, it will look like the cells are bigger, even though the *cells* aren't. It's just the tableView's representation.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is how it's going to be. I was really hoping there would be a way around this as calculating the height of each cell is going to be a pain.

Comment: @JamesDobson Depending on your content, you probably won't have to *calculate* each cell. If, as you said, you only need *one* cell to be taller, and you know which one it is (which index in your data source), you can simply do something like this in `heightForRow..`(let's say the tall one is the fifth element): `if(indexPath.row == 4)return 88; else return 44;` and that's it. However, if it's a dynamic dataSource, that will change its content over time, then that's a no-go. However, the same logic applies.

Comment: Various cells need to have their height calculated; one cell holds the tags (the one in my question) but the other cells have comment and description labels which could be anything from blank to several paragraphs, so to my knowledge I can't do half measures - I either calculate for every cell (or at least define the height, which is possible as some cells have specific heights) or I rely on autolayout with constraints which has worked up till now, since I need to add this new view programmatically.

Comment: Ok. I've never used that, and it seems from the answers and comments here that it's only supported in iOS8. Just remember that if you are going to support any other iOS than iOS8, AutoLayout won't work for displaying the correct height. I have a custom UITableViewCell with lots of information in it, with a textView in the center. It will scale properly by using AutoLayout, but the representation won't look correct. The cells will mingle. You would need to calculate "how many lines of text will this need when it's *this* wide?" You essentially take "cell.height(without text) + lines*lineHeight"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 8 you can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension.You can check out this [example](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

You can take a look also on this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#226) : What's New in Table and Collection Views in the 2014 WWDC.

Comment: that' really cool, thanks for showing that. Unfortunately we need to support iOS 7 so I don't think I'll be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue with a variable for that row's height. In `viewDidLoad()` store default cell height to the variable. then while you calculate the height for the view store the view's height to the variable and to reload that cell use below method for the tableview by passing single cell's indexpath in array.

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

It will update cell at particular index by calling all lifecycle method of a cell.

Make sure you return default value for all other cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` except the cell with tagsView with calculated height cell.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexpath.row == TAGSVIEW_ROWINDEX)
        return calculated_height_value;
    return default_row_height;
}
```

If the Cell with tagsView is not predefined with rowIndex, you can also store that rowIndex in one integer variable in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`.